# iOS xcode Button isn't linking.

Tags: ios, xcode, button

I have a one button on my main storyboard. I'm pretty sure it's linked up correctly but when I run the simulator and hit the button, it does nothing.  What am I missing to get the button to open Safari?

**Viewcontroller.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface testViewController : UIViewController
- (IBAction)openSafari:(id)sender;

@end
```

**Viewcontroller.m**

```
#import "testViewController.h"

@interface testViewController ()

@end

@implementation testViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (IBAction)openSafari:(id)sender {
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.google.com"]];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A URL needs a method as well as an address, so try @"http://www.google.com".  To prove whether your action is hooked up right, print a log message from the method (or use a breakpoint).

Comment: Thank you, adding http fixed the issue, I'm glad it was something simple!